# Find value in a specific column and use it for for create new sheets

Tags: excel, vba, find

I need to create a Macro on excel that perform a quiet strange action but let me explain:
I need to search in a specific column if there's some value (they are eventually all number) and for each value that the macro finds I need to create a copy of an already existing sheets named "template" with the same value that the macro found.

For example, if the macro find the value "3, 9, and 12" I need it to create the sheets "template3, template9, and template12, that must be a copy of "template" that have only a different name based on what the macro founds.

I'm starting from here

```
   Dim FoundArea As Range
   Set FoundArea = Range("I17:I85").Find()
```

I've dected the column in which I want to search for the values, but now I don't know how to tell the program the rest of the actions to perform. Any suggest?
Thanks

UPDATE: I've done it, the first part at least, here's my code if can interest someone

```
Sub AggiornaColliTEST()

'Crea un nuovo foglio di nome "Collo"+valore (se non esiste già) per ogni valore trovato nella colonna i a partire dalla riga 18

Dim sheets_count As Integer
Dim sheet_name As String
Dim j As Integer

sheet_count = Range("I1:I850").Rows.Count
For j = 1 To sheet_count

    sheet_name = Sheets("LISTA MATERIALE").Range("I18:I850").Cells(j, 1).Value
    
    If SheetCheck(sheet_name) = False And sheet_name <> "" Then
    Worksheets.Add().Name = "Collo" & sheet_name
    Worksheets("Collo" & sheet_name).Move After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    
    ElseIf SheetCheck(sheet_name) = True Then
    
    Else
    End If
    
 Next j
    
    
Dim xTable As ListObject
Dim xSheet As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer

For i = 3 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
        'For Each xSheet In Worksheets
        For Each xTable In Sheets(i).ListObjects

            Sheets(2).ListObjects("Tabella10").Range.Copy _
                Destination:=Sheets(i).Range("A17")

            'Sheets(i).Range("D1").Value = xTable.Name
            Sheets(i).ListObjects(xTable.Name).Range.AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:= _
            i - 2
        Next xTable
Next

End Sub
```

here's the custom function used (found this on the internet and work as well)

```
Function SheetCheck(sheet_name As String) As Boolean
'Questa funzione verifica se un foglio con un dato nome esiste già oppure no, ritorna un valore di tipo bool (true o false)


Dim ws As Worksheet
SheetCheck = False
 
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    If ws.Name = "Collo" & sheet_name Then
        SheetCheck = True
    End If
Next
 
End Function
```

The only part I need now is how to copy my template in every new sheet that the Macro create but I'm not so far from the solution. Thanks everybody for helping.

Comment: Create an `Array` of the numbers to find, and loop through it, trying to find each number.

Comment: Thanks , I'm going to create a dynamic array of the found values but how to find and store them in it?

Comment: First you can use the macro recorder to get an idea how something would look like as VBA code. Just make sure you read [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) and re-work the recorded code as it is usually full of `.Select` statements. • Also reading the manual of the methods you use will help you to understand how they work. For example the [Range.Find method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find).

Comment: Thanks. The thing I'm stucked with now is how to use the .Find method in order to search for generic integer value. Every example that I can found search for some specific value. If I want to use .find to find all the generic integer in the Area I decided how can I do? 

PS I'm not sure if .find is available to do it, maybe I should look for something else, is there a method that permit to search for a generic integer?
Thanks all for the support

Comment: Sounds like you'll just need to loop through and check.

Comment: You mean a loop that search for number 1 the first time, number 2 the second time and so on? Maybe I can do something similar. The problem is that I don't know the maximum number that I will be able to find in the table but I think going until 999 is enough.

Comment: nope guys I'm not able to do it, any help with the code would be very useful to me. 
I'm trying to create a dynamic array where I want to store the found value but without any success.

Comment: No, loop through, see what is a number and process from there, no need to do multiple loops.

Comment: I'm going check for that, thanks man